# Problem in passing value of JTable cell of one JFrame form to another form's JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have two JFrame Forms-SelectContactsfrm.java and Taskfrm.java. There is JTable in SelectContactsfrm file to show the contacts.When user select a contact from JTable and when he/she press OK button,selected values should be copied into Taskfrm.java's JTextField.

Taskfrm.java's JTextField's name is-txtContacts and access modifier is-public

Below is the code which I wrote on SelectContactsfrm's OK button's actionPerformed.Button name-btnOK

```
private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Code to get the selected rows value and paste Contact's full name in Taskfrm's txtContacts JTextField:        

    selrow=ctable.getSelectedRow();
    selcol=ctable.getSelectedColumn();
    Object value=ctable.getModel().getValueAt(selrow,1);
    new Taskfrm().txtContacts.setText(value.toString());                                                            

    //Just to check whether I get the correct values or not.                                      
    System.out.println("selrow=="+selrow);
    System.out.println("selcol=="+selcol);
    System.out.println("txtContacts=="+value);

}
```

I can see the correct selected values in output but didnt get why this value has not been set in Taskfrm's JTextField.In Taskfrm's constructor only initComponents() is there.Is there any way to attach class files here instead of pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set its visibility and made changes in Taskfrm's constructor.Now its working.

```
new Taskfrm(value);  
new Taskfrm(value).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Note that every time you do 'new Taskfrm()', you are creating a different instance of that class. That means that the first line is creating an object that is not used afterwards. What you see is the object created in the second line. Consider declaring a variable for the form: Taskfrm myForm = new Taskfrm(value); myForm.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how Taskfrm is set up and what is in it's constructor.
I tried something like this and it works

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ClassA extends JFrame {
    JTextField text;

    public ClassA() {
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Name: ");
        text = new JTextField(20);
        JButton b = new JButton("Send");
        setLayout(null);
        l.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
        text.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        b.setBounds(120, 40, 80, 20);
        add(l);
        add(text);
        add(b);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 100);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new ClassB().text.setText(ClassA.this.text.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new ClassA();
    }
}

class ClassB extends JFrame {
    JTextField text;

    public ClassB() {
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Name: ");
        text = new JTextField(20);

        setLayout(null);
        l.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
        text.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);

        add(l);
        add(text);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of a null layout. Newbies tend to copy code without understanding why it is used. Layout managers should be promoted. In fact the code is easier to understand if you just change the layout manager to a FlowLayout.